# VSCode: Show git changes for active workspace only

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there an option to limit displayed git changes in vscode to active workspace?

In my scenario I have a folder with .git repo and 5 checked out different folders. Each one of them is a part of project I'd like to open in vscode separately and make vscode track changes only for that folder. What it does instead is displaying all changes in repo in all open workspaces.

Folder structure:

```
/.git
/ProjectA
/ProjectB
/ProjectC
...
```

When I open for example ProjectA in vscode instance and then ProjectB in another instance and I make any change in files, I see the change on the source control tab in all opened vscode instances instead of the only one which workspace had this change.

Comment: Why would you do that ?

Comment: Because due to how the code was written I am unable to split them to separate repositories without additional hassle and when some of the projects are launched in vscode debug they make changes in different projects.

Comment: I suppose VSCode is displaying changes in the folder, so once you change it the editor is updating the change... maybe you need to change to something with reloading a file if it is changed wia another instance...

Comment: @Jswk It is like 4 years and I encountered the same problem. Did you figure out a solution for the same ?

Comment: @IndraChatterjee No, I gave up, but I think since last year there's an option in vscode to display uncommited changes in git as a tree which makes this easier to manage as you can see from which project folder the change comes from.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the UI misleading when you want to commit? The UI might hide staged changes from files outside the workspace but tracked in the git repo.